# UIWebView delegate method shouldStartLoadWithRequest: equivalent in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have a module inside my iOS 7+ app which is a UIWebView. The html page loads a javascript that creates custom-shaped buttons (using the Raphaeljs library). With UIWebView, I set delegate to self. The delegate method `webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:` is called each time one of my custom button is pressed. The requests should not be handled by the html, but rather by the iOS code. So I used a request convention (read somewhere here on stackoverflow) using "inapp" as the scheme of my requests. I then check for the host and take the appropriate action.

This code works fine on iOS 7. But the web views appear blank on iOS 8 (bug?), so I decided to use WKWebView for iOS 8 devices. The web views now render fine (and amazingly faster!), but my buttons have no effect.

I tried using `- (WKNaviation *)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request`, but it's not called.

I can't find a direct equivalent of the UIWebView delegate method `webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:`. What's the best way of handling those requests with WKWebView?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Re-reading your description it looks like what you actually need to know about is how to reimplement a Javascript/Objective-C bridge using WKWebView.

I've just done this myself, following the tutorial at http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/objective-c-wkwebview-to-javascript-and-back/ and the info at http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/

WKWebView has a built-in way of communicating between Javascript and Objective-C/Swift: `WKScriptMessageHandler`.

First, include the WebKit headers and `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol in your view controller's header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <WKScriptMessageHandler>

@end
```

The when initialising your `WKWebView`, you need to configure it with a script message handler. Name it whatever you want, but to me it seems like naming it for your app makes sense.

```
    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = 
          [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    [theConfiguration.userContentController 
          addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"myApp"];

    _theWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame 
                      configuration:theConfiguration];
    [_theWebView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:_theWebView];
```

Now, implement `userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:`. This fires when your webview receives a message, so it does the work you were previously doing with `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController 
                        didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
    NSDictionary *sentData = (NSDictionary *)message.body;
    NSString *messageString = sentData[@"message"];
    NSLog(@"Message received: %@", messageString);
}
```

You're now ready to receive messages from Javascript. The function call you need to add to your Javascript is this:

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.myApp.postMessage({"message":"Hello there"});
```

Comment: First, I apologize for the delay. I tested your solution for one of my links, and it worked. Thank you! I will apply the solution everywhere now. Though, I can see my web content on the simulator, but I can't see it on my device. On the device, I still see a blank page. Any idea why?

Comment: @invalidArgument Are you loading the web content from the web, or your bundle? Because I've since learned there's a bit of a bad bug in WKWebView for loading local content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-working-in-ios-8-beta-4

Comment: It is loaded from my bundle. I just posted a question entirely dedicated to the blank page issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26455432/873436. That link was very helpful, thanks again. It led to another issue, though.

Comment: It's so complicated. Why not use decidePolicyForNavigationAction?

Comment: @OpenThread FWR decidePolicyForNavigationAction does not fire, but userContentController does and it is not, actually, that much complicated.

Answer (score 127):

I've been looking for a good explanation myself, but haven't found one. I've used the following in my app and everything seems to work (**Edit:** updated based on [ccoroom's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128815/uiwebview-delegate-method-shouldstartloadwithrequest-equivalent-in-wkwebview/26134994#comment54783498_26134994)):

```
UIWebViewDelegate     - webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
WKNavigationDelegate  - webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:
```

Here's the other `UIWebViewDelegate` methods:

```
UIWebViewDelegate     - webViewDidStartLoad:
WKNavigationDelegate  - webView:didCommitNavigation:

UIWebViewDelegate     - webViewDidFinishLoad:
WKNavigationDelegate  - webView:didFinishNavigation:

UIWebViewDelegate     - webView:didFailLoadWithError:
WKNavigationDelegate  - webView:didFailNavigation:withError:
                      - webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:
```

I'd love for someone to confirm this for me though.

**Edit:** Actually, I've answered the question you had in the title (although I'm no longer confident that `webView:didCommitNavigation:` is called at the exact same point in the lifecycle), but re-reading your description it looks like what you actually need to know about is how to reimplement a Javascript/Objective-C bridge using WKWebView. So have a look at my other answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but a major difference between webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: and webView:didStartProvisionalNavigation: seems to be that the latter does not get the NSUrlRequest.  How do you get information about the request?

Comment: @ajh158 You can get the URL from WkWebView.URL, but I'm not sure about other request details.

Comment: I wouldn't say your first two are the same, since you cannot evaluate the request and stop it in WKNavigationDelegate.

Comment: "webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:"'s counterpart is "webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:"

Comment: This answers the question's title. The question's body is really a separate question, as @SeanR hints at.

Comment: @ajh158 We can get the request from WKNavigationAction (`WKNavigationAction.request`) in 
`- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;`
You should use the above delegate method in place of `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.

Answer (score 75):

To answer the original question, the equivalent of `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in UIWebView is `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:` in WKWebView.  These methods are called before each request is made (including the initial request) and provide the ability to allow/disallow it.

Answer (score 38):

Just use the following method , it's a part of WKNavigationDelegate

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

    NSURLRequest *request = navigationAction.request;
    NSString *url = [[request URL]absoluteString];

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Comment: decidePolicyForNavigationAction it's not calling. Do I need to add any thing else to call this method in my javascript side?

Answer (score 13):

In **Swift** you can do something like this:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    switch navigationAction.request.URLString {
    case "http://action.is.needed/some-action":
        self.someFunc()
        decisionHandler(.Cancel)
        break
    default:
        decisionHandler(.Allow)
        break
    }

}
```

And this is the link in web page:

```
<a href="http://action.is.needed/some-action">Hello world!</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

for **swift 4.2**: 
(taking from Yifei He 何一非. )

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        let url = navigationAction.request.url
        let urlStr = url?.absoluteString
        switch urlStr {
        case BASE_URL:
            //self.someFunc()
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            break
        default:
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            break
        }

    }
```

Comment: decidePolicyFor often will not be reached because the provisional navigation will fail

Answer (score 1):

You can add Observer for your WKWebView

```
 static void* keyValueObservingContext = &keyValueObservingContext;

[webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"URL" options:0 context:keyValueObservingContext];


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
 {

if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"URL"]){
// do something
  }
}
```

Don't forget to remove it in viewWillDisappear

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[webView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"URL"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for Delegate methods on migrate for **UIWebview** to **WKWebview**

**UIWebViewDelegate => WKNavigationDelegate**

1. delegate => NavigationDelegate
2. didFailLoadWithError => didFailNavigation
3. webViewDidFinishLoad => didFinishNavigation
4. webViewDidStartLoad => didStartProvisionalNavigation
5. shouldStartLoadWithRequest => decidePolicyForNavigationAction