# UIWebView objectivists-c using webkit showing depreciated on viewdidload

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I'm trying to create a `UIWebView` in objective-c . I get deprecation error so I tried to use recommended webkit `WkWebview` but at a point I still get error here

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

}
```

I have tried using it this way but yet get new error `Implementing deprecated method`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(WKWebView *)webView{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WKWebView version of webViewDidFinishLoad is this: (in Objective-C syntax)

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {

}
```

Comment: Please is there a place I can fine all the methods that change in webkit? like `- (void)webViewDidStartLoad` etc

Comment: This answer has a few of them:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128815/uiwebview-delegate-method-shouldstartloadwithrequest-equivalent-in-wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `UIWebView` name with `WKWebView` on the delegate method `webViewDidFinishLoad` doesn't work as it is the delegate method for `UIWebView`. You need to use the original delegate method for `WKWebView`.

As per documentation, you should [use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview)

> func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
>               didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)

instead of

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

}
```

On migrating to `WKWebView` you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665141/how-to-migrate-to-wkwebview)